# why fminsearch and fminunc gives different answer when doing optimization?

Tags: matlab

The problem may be related to mathematical theory or may not, still I would like to ask here. I have a `TESTCase.m` as follow:

```
function ret=TESTCase(Input,k)

if k==1
    if Input(2)~=1
        Input(2)=1;
        ret=(Input(1)-2).^2+5.*Input(2).^2;
    end
else if k~=1
        ret=(Input(1)-2).^2+(Input(2)-Input(1)).^2;
    end
end
```

Then, I try to use the fminunc and fminsearch as follow:

```
TEST=@(x)TESTCase(x,1); fminsearch(TEST,[5,3]); fminunc(TEST,[5,3]);
```

I get two answers respectively:
`2.0000    3.9000` (using fminsearch) and `2.0000    3.0000` (using fminunc)

I know that the two answers are correct under my function defined, but I wonder why it changes the second value when using `fminsearch` but show no changes when using `fminunc`. It is odd to me. Also, when using fminsearch, no messages are displayed, but using fminunc, the following messages are displayed:

```
Warning: Gradient must be provided for trust-region algorithm;
  using line-search algorithm instead. 

 In fminunc at 382 

Local minimum found.

Optimization completed because the size of the gradient is less than
the default value of the function tolerance.
```

`<stopping criteria details>`. What are the differences? I know `fminsearch` is derivative free and `fminunc` is not, but if the message outputs, it should mean that `fminunc` is also derivative free in this case; under the circumstance, they should be equivalent.

Comment: Please use block code formatting for code blocks to enable syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

`fminsearch` and `fminunc` use different derivative free algorithms: `fminsearch` uses some kind of [simplex search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method) method,  `fminunc` uses [line search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_search).
As a result of a properly chosen descent direction `fminunc` finds a minimum in two iterations:

```
Iteration  Func-count       f(x)        Step-size       optimality
 0           3               14                             6
 1           6                9       0.166667              4  
 2           9                5              1              0
```

The simplex method is not quite optimal in this case. The optimization details for `fminsearch` are as follow:

```
Iteration   Func-count     min f(x)         Procedure
 0            1               14         
 1            3               14         initial simplex
 2            5            11.25         expand
 3            6            11.25         reflect
 4            8             7.25         expand
 5            9             7.25         reflect
 6           11             5.25         reflect
 7           12             5.25         reflect
 8           14                5         contract outside
 9           15                5         reflect
10           17                5         contract inside
11           19                5         contract inside
12           21                5         contract inside
13           23                5         contract inside
14           25                5         contract inside
15           27                5         contract inside
16           29                5         contract inside
17           31                5         contract inside
18           33                5         contract inside
19           35                5         contract inside
20           37                5         contract inside
21           39                5         contract inside
22           41                5         contract inside
23           43                5         contract inside
24           45                5         contract inside
25           47                5         contract inside
26           49                5         contract inside
27           51                5         contract inside
28           53                5         contract inside
29           55                5         contract inside
30           57                5         contract inside
31           59                5         contract inside
32           61                5         contract inside
33           63                5         contract inside
34           65                5         contract inside
35           69                5         shrink
36           73                5         shrink
37           77                5         shrink
38           81                5         shrink
39           85                5         shrink
40           89                5         shrink
41           93                5         shrink
42           97                5         shrink
43          101                5         shrink
44          105                5         shrink
45          109                5         shrink
```

It's really hard to say why the result of `fminsearch` is precisely `2.0000    3.9000`.  The way to the minimum was not easy...